# Issue when i uploading files named in greek characters in production env, but not in the localhot env

Tags: php, file, file-upload, server, upload

I am using a php framework called Scriptcase, so in this framework i have a simple form and a file input in order to upload my files into the server.

Localhost when i am uploading greek named files from my pc (jpg, png etc..) everything works fine.
For example if have a file named `ελλαδα0123.png` it is uploaded correctly into to my server.

But in the Production env, if i go to upload the exact same file named "ελλαδα0123.png" it's uploaded like that `Ξ•Ξ¥Ξ”Ξ‘Ξ  Ξ Ξ•Ξ™Ξ΅Ξ‘Ξ™Ξ0123.png`.

I think is a problem with the encoding, but this is only happeping when it comes to uploading greek named files into the production environment. If i upload files named in english characters everything works fine everywhere (localhost and production env).
Note: I have never had a problem with the database (sql) utf-8 characters.

Do anyone know why is this happening in the production environment only?
Thank you.

```
`// This is my code

sc_api_download([
'settings' => [
'gateway' => 'dropbox',
'api_key' => {apikey},
'api_secret' => {apisecret},
'access_token' => {accesstoken},
],
  'file' => $usersFile,
  'destination' => tmp/files/,
]);

// At the end of the script the framework itself is doing the execution (uploading the file)`
```

Comment: I had something similar recently with `file_exists` returning false with accented characters, does `utf8_decode($usersFile)` help you?

Comment: If i `echo utf8_decode($usersFile)` i get `??????0123.png` which is my file ελλαδα0123.png

Comment: Yes in my case too, the display may be wrong, but the function worked, just thought it could help you but I wasn't sure.. you can still give it a try

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @KenLee I will test it and i will you give a feedback thanks